# Exclude packages from Jacoco report using Sonarrunner and Gradle

Tags: gradle, jacoco, sonar-runner

Is there a way to exclude packages from SonarQube(instrumented by gradle + sonar-runner) coverage reports(generated by jacoco) without excluding them completely from the project ?

Below is what i tried so far:

### Version information

- SonarQube 4.5.1
- Gradle 2.2.

### Jacoco configuration

```
// JaCoCo test coverage configuration
tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
    jacoco {
        append = false

        // excluded classes from coverage defined in above configuration
        excludes = excludedClasses()
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        doFirst {
            classDirectories = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/classes/main/").exclude(excludedClasses())
        }
    }

}
```

### Sonarrunner configuration

Property setting to exclude package from Sonar analysis. Adding this to my configuration lead to the situation that the packages do not show-up at all in Sonar.

```
property 'sonar.exclusions', excludedClasses().join(',')
```

---

Property setting to exclude packages from jacoco. Setting this leads to the situation that packages are excluded from coverage analysis however show up having 0% which accumulates to bad total scores.

```
property 'sonar.jacoco.exclusions', excludedClasses().join(',')
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have managed to exclude particular packages from coverage reports by using **sonar.coverage.exclusions** property in sonar-project.properties. Property is described in official [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-5)

Comment: Gradle config: `sonarqube {
 properties{
  property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', "**/com/some/package/*,**/com/other/package/Class*"
 }
}`

Comment: Correct working pattern is : sonarqube { 
  properties { 
     property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', '**/model/*, **/commons/*, **/exception/*, **/controller/*, **/utils/*, **/Test.java'
  } 
}

Comment: the link is corrupted @Mikalai-Parafeniuk

Answer (score 19):

To combine @Mikalai's answer and @pavel's comment into something that's a bit easier to copy and paste:

To exclude a package or class from **all** Sonar checks (coverage, code smells, bugs etc), add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/com/some/package/**"
    }
}
```

To exclude a package or class from only Sonar code coverage checks, add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', "**/com/some/package/**"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running sonar v7.9 and configured the same in my build.gradle. Still sonar dashboard show these classes as 0% coverage. Is there any other config/setting required?

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Gradle 5+ with Kotlin DSL, you can exclude the files from coverage like this:

```
// configure the SonarQube plugin
sonarqube {
    val exclusions = listOf(
        "**/com/some/package/**",
        "**/all/files/under/package/*",
        "**/com/some/package/OneClass.kt"
    )

    // exclude the directories only from coverage (but not from other analysis)
    // https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/
    properties {
        property("sonar.coverage.exclusions", exclusions)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To exclude res, assets, custom packages and auto generated classes from sonar code coverage for android project.

Create Exclusion list like below

```
exclusionList = [
            //Res and Assets
            "src/main/res/**/*.*",
            "src/main/assets/**/*.*",

            //Auto-Generated
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/*Manifest.*',
            'android/**/*.*',
            'androidx/**/*.*',

            // excluded packages
            **/com/<your-package-path>/**/*]
```

Provide the exclusion list to sonar coverage property

```
property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', exclusionList
```

NOTE:

- Keep the full path to exclude the full directory
- **/* includes all the files and sub directories under the parent directory [Refer Here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/)
- *Bean includes all the class names contains "Bean".
- **/ starting with it covers the parent directories for the particular package.

Run Jacoco command and check sonar portal's coverage section after doing above changes.

Answer (score 4):

> exclude multiple module or class from Sonarqube. add below code to
>   build.gradle:

**example** : 
  package name= com.student.result.detail , com.customer.order ,com.student

```
  sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/com/student/result/details/**",
                                     "**/com/customer/order/**",
                                     "**/com/student/**";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with gradle 6, sonarqube plugin 2.8

`property "sonar.coverage.exclusions" , "**/com/some/package/entity/**/*," +                "**/com/some/package/config/**/*,**/com/some/package/dto/**/*,**/com/some/package/dao/**/*"`

NOTE: packages are comma separated but in a single string

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answer I have seen here didn't work for me, resulting on the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Could not find method property() for arguments [sonar.coverage.exclusions, **/package/path/Class1**, **/package/path/Class2**, **/package/path/Class3**, **/package/path/Class4**] on object of type org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeProperties.
```

The reason is that sonar is asking for a string instead of several comma-separated strings as property value. So instead of:

```
  sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/com/student/result/details/**",
                                     "**/com/customer/order/**",
                                     "**/com/student/**";
        }
    }
```

The solution for me was:

```
  sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/com/student/result/details/**,"+
                                     "**/com/customer/order/**,"+
                                     "**/com/student/**";
        }
    }
```