# Exclude package from Jacoco report using gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

I have tried both approach shared here and on another discussion board.

Inside jacocoTestReport - suggested in this [blog](https://liviutudor.com/2016/02/11/jacoco-gradle-excluding-source-files-and-classes/#sthash.4vQOedkq.ThYrwZDe.dpbs)

```
    afterEvaluate { 
       classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect { 
           fileTree(
             dir: "build/classes/main", exclude: ['*/com.X.Y.P/**']) 
        }) 
    }
```

and inside sonarqube as suggest in one another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033757/exclude-packages-from-jacoco-report-using-sonarrunner-and-gradle)

```
property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "*/com.X.Y.P/**"
```

But none of them is working for me.

```
Gradle version -    2.13
jacoco toolVersion = "0.7.4.201502262128"
sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2
springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (basically, replace the `"build/classes/main"` by `it`)

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/Q*')
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes but still not working.




Here is code :
    jacocoTestReport{
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
    reports {
  html.enabled true
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "build/reports/jacoco/html"
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/com.xyz.domain*')
        })
    }
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec')
}

Comment: `*/com.xyz.domain` won't match much, the package separator is /. Try `**/com/xyz/domain/**`

Comment: Thanks ToYonos,  I tried with `**/com/xyz/domain/**` and `**/com/xyz/**`, nothing is changing, getting all packages included in report.

Comment: That's the only solution I found on SO, which solved my problem with ignoring several classes, which were generated and I didn't want to measure their coverage. Thanks!